# Sign and send signed transaction in L2 zk-Rollup

Tags: web3js, blockchain, truffle, erc-20, layer-2

I own an **ERC20** token on the Ethereum mainnet but as everyone knows the fees are very high would it be possible use **L2 zk-Rollup** with this methods below?

Example `transfer()`, `estimateGas()`, `getTransactionCount()`, `decodeData()`, `signTransaction()` and `sendSignedTransaction()`.

I currently use `Alchemy` for my RPC in `Web3.js` I've been researching and found these endpoints `Ankr` and `Chainstack` with `Harmony`, `Fantom`, `Polygon`, `Gnosis`, `Celo` and `Moonriver` but I don't know if these endpoints support these methods above, someone who has already gone through this could mention their solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i am runing tests in `POA Sokol` and is work!